# C++ - Data structure/algorithm that can keep track of structures (x and y) and values avoiding duplicates

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure to use for a program I am working on. It keeps track of x and y values and needs to set the Z only if the x,y location isn't already my array.

I tried using a dynamic array and as the list grows, it becomes very very slow to iterate over the data. Here is what my structure looks like.

struct pos
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

The corresponding value is an integer that is only set if the x,y pair doesn't exist.

Edit: I have been trying to use a map but couldn't figure out how to use an x, y coordinate has the index, i.e. how to .insert(pos, zValue);

Comment: std:multimap perhaps. That will let you quickly search for the existence of any pair, but also allow you to store multiple identical pairs. But not completely sure I understand.

Comment: Yeah, rereading your question std::map seems right.

Comment: @UmNyobe I was thinking about a map but how would I store a 2 component vector as the index.

Comment: @john can you give me the syntax for insertion of a map value that would work with a 2 component vector as the index.

Comment: `my_map[p] = n;`, same as any other map

Comment: `my_map.insert(make_pair(p, n));` works as well.

Comment: No, he's asking what the key and value types should be

Comment: @john I can use 'pos', my structure as the index? I was getting: Error 1 error C2664: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'pos' to 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'

Comment: As long as you've defined operator< for pos then you can.

Comment: @john Is this done via operator overloading?

Comment: Looks like you are calling the wrong version of insert. In your error message insert has two parameters.

Comment: `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> xy_to_z_mapping;` avoid using your own type and having to provide comparison operators.

Comment: Yes operator overloading.

Comment: Yes, use overloading. The reason you need to do it is that std::map is a sorted container so you need to provide a way to determine the sorting order.

Comment: If you only want the uniqueness property and the ability to iterate, you're better off using unordered_map btw (provided you have access to a C++11 compiler). It's faster for insertion and deletion.

Comment: @andre Is there anything else I need to do when inserting into this map? Still getting errors: Error 1 error C2664: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'

Comment: Probably need something like `m.insert(pair<pair<int, int>, int>(pair<int, int>(x, y), z)` -- nice and unwieldy :)

Comment: You can insert into a map with one of two methods. `xy_to_z_mapping[std::make_pair(x,y)] = z;` or `xy_to_z_mapping.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(x,y),z));`

Answer (score 4):

You could use a map or if you are using a C++ 11 compiler an unordered_map to keep an index of the points.

Answer (score 1):

To fully elaborate of how to insert into `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> xy_to_z_mapping;`

```
std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int> point(int x, int y, int z) {
    return std::make_pair(std::make_pair(x,y),z);
}

xy_to_z_mapping.insert(point(x,y,z));
```

Or,

```
xy_to_z_mapping.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(x,y),z));
```

Or,

```
xy_to_z_mapping[std::make_pair(x,y)] = z;
```

Answer (score 0):

As andre said, to avoiding overloading operators on your struct you can use the following map:

`std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> a_map;`

**Insertion:**

Insert into it with `a_map.insert(std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, int>(std::pair<int,int>(x, y), z));`

or

`std::pair<int, int> index(x, y);
a_map[index] = z;`

or (neatest version, borrowed from andre's answer)

`a_map[make_pair(x, y)] = z;`

**Access:**

If you're only iterating through the elements and don't particularly care about accessing values by their index very often this method is fine. If you *do* want to do that then you can access them like so:

`std::pair<int, int> index(x, y);
int z = a_map[index];`

or (neatest version)

`int z = a_map[make_pair(x, y)];`

You could also use `find()` but once again, you'll need to construct a `pair` for it (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/).

You can use the `make_pair()` function from `<utility>` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/) to make constructing the pairs a bit easier but if you don't want to use a map with pairs as the indexes then you might want to revert to the original plan and use an `std::map<pos, int>` instead.

**Alternative map:**

If you decide to use `std::map<pos, int>` just remember to overload `operator<` on `pos` to allow your `map` to sort its keys (since you aren't actually making any use of the sorting feature, you can return the comparison of either `pos::x` or `pos::y` arbitrarily).

**Unordered map:**

If you want to avoid the need to overload the operator and the sorting entirely, you can use the new C++11 `unordered_map` which is a more efficient container for insertions and deletions anyway. Since you're only using the uniqueness and iterator properties of `map`, it would be worth considering using `unordered_map` if you can (they have very similar interfaces and I've used them in place of `map` just by changing the type of my variable before!)

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat think that the correct data structure seems to be a set, rather than a map. The reason is that if you are dealing with `Point`s or `Position`s, the data type contains the three coordinates (`x`, `y`, and `z`).

Now, you seem to be interested in updating a `Position`'s `z`-coordinate only if another point with the same `x`- and `y`-coordinate has not been updated yet.

I created the following implementation using an unordered set. Notice that the hasher and comparator only use `x` and `y`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>

template<typename T>
struct Position {
  Position(T x, T y, T z)
      : x(x),
        y(y),
        z(z) {}
  T x, y, z;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Position<T>& p) {
  os<<"("<<p.x<<", "<<p.y<<", "<<p.z<<")";
  return os;
}

struct point_equal {
  template<typename T>    
  bool operator()(const Position<T>& p1, const Position<T>& p2) const {
    return (p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y);
  }
};

struct point_hash {
  template<typename T>    
  std::size_t operator()(const Position<T>& p) const {
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    return hasher(p.x) ^ hasher(p.y);
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Particles {
 public:
  bool add(T x, T y, T z) {
    return m_particles.emplace(x, y, z).second;
  }
  void show() const {
    for(auto p : m_particles) {
      std::cout<<p<<std::endl;
    }    
  }
 private:
  typedef std::unordered_set<Position<T>, point_hash, point_equal> Container;
  Container m_particles;
};


int main() {
  Particles<int> p;
  std::cout<<std::boolalpha;  
  std::cout<<"should show (1, 2, 3)"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Added new point? "<<p.add(1, 2, 3)<<std::endl;  
  p.show();
  std::cout<<"should show (1, 2, 3) again"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Added new point? "<<p.add(1, 2, 4)<<std::endl;
  p.show();
  std::cout<<"should show (1, 2, 3) and (3, 4, 5)"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Added new point? "<<p.add(3, 4, 5)<<std::endl;  
  p.show();
  std::cout<<"should show (1, 2, 3) and (3, 4, 5) again"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Added new point? "<<p.add(3, 4, 9)<<std::endl;    
  p.show();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ example.cpp -std=c++11` (using GCC 4.7.2) I get the following result:

```
should show (1, 2, 3)
Added new point? true
(1, 2, 3)
should show (1, 2, 3) again
Added new point? false
(1, 2, 3)
should show (1, 2, 3) and (3, 4, 5)
Added new point? true
(3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3)
should show (1, 2, 3) and (3, 4, 5) again
Added new point? false
(3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3)
```